# How should I perform an asynchronous action within an accessor?

Tags: actionscript-3, asynchronous, accessor

I have a simple accessor in my class:

```
public function get loggedIn():Boolean
{
    var loggedIn:Boolean = somePrivateMethodToCheckStatus();
    return loggedIn;
}
```

The API I'm now working with checks login status in an asynchronous fashion:

```
API_Class.addEventListener(API_Class.LOGIN_STATUS,onStatusCheck);
API_Class.checkLoginStatus();

function onStatusCheck(evt:API_Event):void
{
    //evt.loggedIn == true or false
}
```

Is there a way I can perform this asynchronous request without exiting my accessor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: No, there is not.  You will have to set up login verification in an asynchronous fashion.

I am a bit curious: Why is there a need to repeatedly poll the login status remotely?  If your user logged in from within the Flash application, the status should be known.  Same goes for logging out.  If login and logout is handled from outside the Flash app, why not implement a notification mechanism (via JavaScript or socket connection)?

Also, if not being logged in prevents users from performing actions on the server, you could check for authorization *on the server*, whenever remote calls are made, and return an error if the session has expired.  This would still be more efficient than repeatedly polling status info.

Comment: The user can potentially log in and out from outside of the Flash app, I have no control over anything but the Flash app and I need to reflect the current (to within a few seconds) login status.  I will just have to rewrite my own classes to properly handle this newly asynchronous behaviour.

Comment: You could set up a timer to poll the status every couple of seconds and set a status variable.  Then your accessors could still be synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no. Flash runs in a single thread, and every function has to finish before events etc will be called.

One (sort of) solution would be to return three values; "yes", "no" and "pending". If it's pending the loggedIn()-method would start a check, and the client of that method should check again in a little while.

Another way would be to have the loggedIn-method send the answer to a callback instead. Eg "getLoggedInStatus(callback:Function)"

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-eventbus/index.html
It is a handy lib that focuses on asynchronous jobs.